# Subscribing to a message from multiple publisher in nServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, esb, publish-subscribe

I wonder if it’s possible using nServiceBus to subscribe to all Messages of a Type without specifying the publisher’s end point.

The Background for this, is a distributed  algorithm, that uses the distributor infra structure of nServiceBus to  delegate sub problems  to distributed workers on the network.

After a task is finished, the worker should send a message to  notifying the sender.

I could use IBus.Reply() to notify it but I have also some monitoring and logging services, which are also interested in those messages. Making the sender republish all received replied doesn’t sound right.

Can I subscribe to a message from multiple publisher in nServiceBus?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're exactly right to use [Reply](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/reply-to-a-message) - simple and works.

In order to do logging/monitoring, you can [audit messages](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing) so each endpoint forwards the messages it receives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It answers the question very well.